# mediaplayer start/stop button error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i've read other questions asked before but still have a problem. 
my media player gives me an NPE error when i open my activity and the app crashes.

i'm a beginner. and keep in mind that i have 14 other activities that use mp1, mp2, mp3 and ... . the problem is with my button i guess, i need it to: when clicked start playing, and when clicked again stop playing. thanks.

**Edit: i've changeed my MediaPlayer like this, so i can access it in OnDestroy() method, but now, when i click the button, nothing happens :(, (i've also tried OnPause() and same result.**

```
package ir.tarjomeebook.rkd;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class One extends ActionBarActivity {    

MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);


    MediaPlayer.create(One.this, R.raw.unua);

    //action bar
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //end

        WebView wb1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/unua.html");
        wb1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        //media player btn
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ply_btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaplayer.pause();        
                } else {
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mediaplayer.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.one, menu);
    return true;
}

//menu item select
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Do include your error logs. :)

Comment: final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(One.this, R.raw.dua); Write this statement in side onCreate method for first try. And write Your LOGCAT error if not solved.

Comment: http://8pic.ir/images/0kyxxid6gzlc2uhovwwg.png

Comment: i'm sorry when i want to export my logcat to a .txt file, the file is empty. so i took a picture :(

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwe9iYyAhRzgZEJSaV9UQi1lYUU

Answer (score 0):

set this line at on button click event again.

```
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(One.this, R.raw.dua);
```

Comment: yeah it solved the problem. but now i have another problem, which is: when the activity is destroyed, it still plays sound. what should i write in ondestroy() to make it stop ? tnx

Comment: mp1.pause();  ya m1.stop(); at onDestroy() method

Comment: no i can't access mp1 in onDestroy() method and it says that can't be resolved. :( help please. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2445398 At Initialization MediaPlayer to remove final keyword.

Comment: @user2445398 other wise its define as null

Comment: i removed final and got error. i've changed it like above, and now the button doesn't work no more :| @Hardik Parmar

Comment: @user2445398 i use your code in my Activity first i do set as a final keyword that a time i get error like can't be resolved then i remove to final keyword then its work fine

Comment: @user2445398 and check which media player import package.